# How to debug strange artefacts in django template?

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-templates, pdb

I'm using django template to render my hierarchical tree in a web page. In the process of rendering of a tree I see these strange whitespaces between nodes:

[image]

Here is my recursive template:

index.html:

```
<ul class="Container">
    <li class="IsRoot">
        <div class="Expand">
        </div>
        <div class="Content">
            Содержание
        </div>
    </li>
    {% include 'list.html' with data=list %}
</ul>
```

and list.html (as a recursive part):

```
<ul class="Container">
    <li class="Node ExpandClosed">
        <div class="Expand"></div>
        <div class="Content">
            <a href="/help/{{data.name}}">
                {{data.content}}
            </a>
        </div>
        {% for item in data.decendent %}
            {% include 'list.html' with data=item %}
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to debug what's the matter with this template and in what period of time it happens? As you can see, I don't generate any whitespaces in this template.

Answer (score 1):

The white space is not the problem, and it is not causing the spaces in your rendered tree. The reason for that appears to be that you are nesting `ul` elements directly inside `ul`s, which isn't strictly speaking valid: they should be inside `li`s.

Comment: Unfortunately, this assumption is probably correct but in my case it doesn't solve my problem and in addition breaks the layout. In a way as I described it above, it renders this structure: http://take.ms/sj67a When I'm trying to wrap ul in list.html in li like here: http://take.ms/WqJLu it renders in a broken way: http://take.ms/sN2iT Where am I wrong?

P.S. Tree was implemented like here: http://javascript.ru/ui/tree (you can look at it in the end of the document)